# android:how to load class in another application

Tags: android, class, loader, android-ndk

question description:
   i'm writing a plugin(named plugin) for an android application(named app).
   the pulgin has some native code,and should be called by the app.
   that is to say,the app startup plugin by the native code

app start up 
   -> load plugin's .so library (the .so is loaded in app) 
   -> app invoke a c function in so.
all these works fine.

and when the .so try to load class in plugin,it return classNotDef exception.
   but the class is exist. and if i run the plugin alone,the exception don't appears,
   i guess it is because the so is loaded in app's process,and the plugin is in another 
   package.

anbody can help me

Comment: ur question is not too clear.....please provide some code, wht u have done. It will make ur question clear and understandable.......

Answer (score 0):

Define the class in `AndroidManifest.xml`for the category it is.